# How can I get an modulo of a calculation in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, unix-timestamp, modulo

I am simply trying to get the Unixtime of the current day. For that I wanted to get the modulo of the current time divided by the timespan of one day. .

```
yourUnixTime = k / 86400
modunix = mod yourUnixTime 1
main = do
putStrLn "give me your time"
k <- readLn
putStrLn $ "time: " ++show (modunix yourUnixTime)
```

This is my current code. So why does my code not work?
It says "Variable not in scope: k" I also tried to put a "k" between the "yourUnixTime" and the equal sign, didnt work either (with even more errors I can't understand). So the answer I am hoping for is how I can fix it and/or what other solutions are there.

Comment: At the very least, `yourUnixTime` needs to be a *function*. `k` isn't defined in the scope where you define `yourUnixTime`.

Comment: [Don't try to write your own time-handling library.](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca) Use [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the variable `k` before it has been defined or initialized.

Here is the modified version of the code

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter the current time:"
  k <- readLn
  let (unixTime, modUnix) = k `divMod` 86400
  putStrLn $ "Unix time of the current day: " ++ show modUnix
```